# Strange string issue in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is a simple yet weird one. I have an app that uses a setting to create a string, which then gets put into a rich text box. sounds simple right? But for some weird reason i'm getting an extra line break. Simple example :

if i do this :

```
head = "Some text :" + " some other text"
richtextbox.AppendText(head)
```

the output is

```
Some text : some other text"
```

as you would expect. but if the app does the following :

```
my.settings.variable1 = " some other text"
head = "Some text :" + my.settings.variable1
richtextbox.AppendText(head)
```

the output is

```
Some text :
some other text"
```

ie with a line break i never specified. It's not a word wrap or tab issue as i've tried every variation under the sun to eliminate those possibilities. any ideas?

**** EDIT   ********

I have narrowed down the cause but still makes little sense. The cause is the setting i am using to provide part of the string. the actual code in my app is :

```
 head = "Your Server : " + My.Settings.Server + "....Bill#" + My.Settings.BinNo
```

which somehow puts a line break after my.settings.server. However if i have the exact same line but change the code to :

```
 head = "Your Server : " + My.Settings.BinNo + "....Bill#" + My.Settings.BinNo
```

I no longer see the problem. Bizarre, but progress. Still can't figure out why. Both are string variables, both are same length....

Comment: I just tried exactly what you describe and I see no spurious line break, as one would expect.  If you create a new project with a just a `Button` and a `RichTextBox` and put the code in the `Click` event handler, does it behave as it apparently should?

Comment: I did what you recommended and sure enough, the problem doesn't occur in a clean project. Problem is, I have no idea what other bits of my project could be causing this error, so it's very hard for me to troubleshoot lol. For clarity, the code i posted above was simplified. this is what the ACTUAL line looks like :

Comment: head = "Your Server : " + My.Settings.Server + "....Bill#" + My.Settings.BinNo

Comment: If one case only is in fault, chances are it contains somehow a linebreak. You should try to actually check by code if there is some line separator char in your string. See the example code in [Char.IsSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cta536cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and run it on your setting to see what comes out

Comment: How EXACTLY are you setting `My.Settings.Server`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was strange but simple. There was a recursive bit of code earlier in the module that formatted the string before assigning it to the server setting. It was meant to check the length of the string and pad it to a certain length. However it went awry and added a whole bunch of spaces on the end, so at the end of it all it was not a line feed that made it go to the next line, it was simple word wrap and invisible space characters pushing the text to the right. simple but annoying to find. thanks for the help guys